# Evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: 308 in SwiftUI App

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I am utilizing Firebase and SwiftUI for a personal project. I am working on the auth page, and whenever I log in by pressing the SignIn button this is output in console. I am just curious as to what this means when in the context of auth and why it may occur?

> 2024-03-01 00:24:10.358620-0800 AppName[40641:339881] [connection] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array [C1.1.1 proxy pac] Evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: 308
> 2024-03-01 00:24:10.544679-0800 AppName[40641:340582] [connection] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array [C2.1.1 proxy pac] Evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: 308

my authViewModel:

```
@MainActor
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    
    init(){
        // firebase cache if current user on device is Authenticated, so we can check!
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
    }
    
func login(email: String, password: String) async throws{
    do{
        let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
        self.userSession = result.user
    } catch{
        print("DEBUG \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I am calling this function from my `authViewModel` in a SwiftUI view called `LoginView`:

```
Button{
                    if email.count == 0 || password .count == 0{
                        return
                    }else{
                        Task{
                            try await authViewModel.login(email: email, password: password)
                        }
                    }
                 
                } label: {
                    Text("Sign In")
                        .bold()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
                        
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                            .fill(.linearGradient(colors: [.pink, .red], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .padding(.top)
```

How I navigate to page once user is authenticated:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Group{
            if authViewModel.userSession != nil{
                ListView()
            }else{
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally my swift App file:

```
struct LandanApp: App {
    @StateObject var authViewModel = AuthViewModel()
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate


  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      NavigationView {
        ContentView()
              .environmentObject(authViewModel)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I just pressed "Sign in" and got this message in console log.

Comment: What do you have in AppDelegate?

Comment: @ElTomato It just contain the basic firebase init:                                            
  class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}

Comment: I have only done FirebaseAuth in UIKit once, but don't you need some lines of code for GoogleSignIn in AppDelegate?

Comment: @ElTomato Most likely for that case, but in my case, I am just doing sign in/up with just email and password. Not the most secure but just trying to get an understanding of firebase auth!

Comment: How are you testing your app?  Using the Sim or an actual device?

Comment: @ElTomato just the simulate Xcode provides on the simulator app.